# Chart not appearing in FlowLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, charts

I am trying to add chart as control in flowlayoutpanel but after executing all charts appears blank how to solve this ? here is my code

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear();
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series Series = new Series();
Chart[] chartMensal = new Chart[12];
for (int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
  string[] seriesArray = { "Total Contrato", "Total Vendas", "Total Despeses" };
  Double[] pointsArray = { 1000, 1500, 500 };

  chartMensal[i] = new Chart();
  chartMensal[i].Width = this.Width - 100;
  chartMensal[i].Height = 200;

  chartMensal[i].Titles.Add(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(i).ToUpper());
  chartMensal[i].Palette = ChartColorPalette.Fire;
  chartMensal[i].Series.Clear();
  Series.Points.Clear();

  for (int t = 0; t < seriesArray.Length; t++)
  {
    Series.Points.Add(pointsArray[t]);
    Series = chartMensal[i].Series.Add(seriesArray[t]);
  }

  chartMensal[i].Visible = true;
  flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(chartMensal[i]);
}
```

Comment: tried chartMensal[i].Update() or flowLayoutPanel1.Update()?

Comment: yes but same appears blank.

Comment: BTW: your first for loop counts until 12 and causes a OutOfBoundsException... I think you are missing the Chart area.

Comment: for changing Chart[] chartMensal = new Chart[13]; same thing without exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the chart area itself.
Add before the last line:

```
                ChartArea ca = new ChartArea();
            chartMensal[i].ChartAreas.Add(ca);
```

Have a look how the designer creates a chart. You sure find a solution in this forum, too.